# Constraint validations of DTOs for non-rest methods in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I am using javax + Hibernate validations for DTOs on my REST calls annotated with `@PostMaping, @PutMapping` . It does work very well, but then I also have a spot, where I am merging 2 objects into one DTO and then I am passing it into "Manager" layer, I would love to slap `@Valid` annotation to the argument, I was expecting it to work, but unfortunately, the validation does not kick-in.
Is there a way to force it?

======================UPDATE====================

My class does have `@Validated` annotation on the top. 
The method for which an argument should be validated is `public`.

I have the following beans configured:

```
    @Bean
    public static LocalValidatorFactoryBean defaultValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        MessageInterpolatorFactory interpolatorFactory = new MessageInterpolatorFactory();
        factoryBean.setMessageInterpolator(interpolatorFactory.getObject());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public static MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor(Environment environment, Validator validator) {
        MethodValidationPostProcessor processor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        boolean proxyTargetClass = (Boolean)environment.getProperty("spring.aop.proxy-target-class", Boolean.class, true);
        processor.setProxyTargetClass(proxyTargetClass);
        processor.setValidator(validator);
        return processor;
    }
```

Comment: A way around is validate Dto using build in validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That annotation doesn't work on `@RestController` class methods other than `@RequestMapping`, so I created a dummy validator like so:

```
@Service
@Validated
@Slf4j
public class DTOValidator {

    /**
     * This method triggers DTO validation same way as Spring REST layer does for @RequestMapping method argument.
     */
    public void validate(@Valid DTO dto) {
        log.trace("dto passed the validation = {}", dto);
    }

}
```